# Running script dependent on dbus at startup

Tags: pi-zero-w, systemd

I have a python script that runs a webserver which accepts requests to control video playback via `omxplayer` and [`python-omxplayer-wrapper`](https://github.com/willprice/python-omxplayer-wrapper). I would like to have my script run at startup. `python-omxplayer-wrapper` communicates with `omxplayer` over dbus.

I am running on a Raspberry Pi Zero W with raspbian stretch installed via NOOBS, and is configured as headless.

I have created a service in `/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Type=idle
ExecStart=/home/pi/myscript/server/myserver.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and enabled service via:

```
sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/myservice.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable myservice.service
sudo reboot
```

Running my script manually, or manually starting the service with `systemctld myservice start` after system boot works fine. When my script is run during init, it fails with the following error:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoServer: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-NxYs8GEMQz: Connection refused
```

My interpretation is that init is running my script before the dbus become available, even though I have my script as `Type=idle` which should cause my script to run at the end of the boot sequence.

How can I enforce my service to start only once the dbus connections become available?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's an old question, but I was facing the same problem and this was the solution:

You have to add "bluetooth.target" after "After=multi-user.target", leaving that line like this -> "**After=multi-user.target bluetooth.target**"

Also, keep "**Type=idle**" because if you use "Type=simple" it will not work, even if your service starts after bluetooth service. I think this may be related to dbus service not starting, but didn't check it because this way already works...

Answer (score 0):

I would run it from crontab to make sure the dbus is available before execution.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then add this at the bottom

```
@reboot * * * * python /home/pi/myscript/server/myserver.py
```